# re.sub on a match.group

Tags: python, regex

```
for element in f:
   galcode_scan = re.search(ur'blah\.blah\.blah\(\'\w{5,10}', element)
```

If I try to perform re.sub and remove the blahs with something else and keep the last bit, the \w{5,10} becomes literal. How do I retain the characters that are taken up by that chunk of the regular expression?

EDIT:

Here is the complete code

```
for element in f:
  galcode_scan = re.search(ur'Imgur\.Util\.triggerView\(\'\w{5,10}', element)
  galcode_scan = re.sub(r'Imgur\.Util\.triggerView\(\'\w{5,10}', 'blah\.\w{5,10}',   ur"galcode_scan\.\w{5,10}")
  print galcode_scan
```

Comment: Please post your code that's not working.

Comment: You need to use a capture group to copy part of the input into the output.

Comment: Also post a desired input-output pair to make it easier to understand what do you want to achieve

Comment: I am wanting to change it from Imgur.Util.triggerView\'B1ahblA4 to imgur.com/B1ahblA4. And have it go through every item in the group and perform the same kind of edits.

Answer (score 1):

You can use positive lookahead (`(?=...)`) to not to match when replacing but matching as a whole pattern:

```
re.sub("blah\.blah\.blah\(\'(?=\w{5,10})", "", "blah.blah.blah('qwertyu")
```

> 'qwertyu'

If you want to replace you match, just add it to the replacement parameter:

```
re.sub("blah\.blah\.blah\(\'(?=\w{5,10})", "pref:", "blah.blah.blah('qwertyu")
```

> 'pref:qwertyu'

You can also do it by capturing the pattern (`(..)`) and back-referencing it (`\1` .. `\9`):

```
re.sub("blah\.blah\.blah\(\'(\w{5,10})", "pref:\\1", "blah.blah.blah('qwertyu")
```

> 'pref:qwertyu'

**Update**

A more precise pattern for the provided exmples:

```
re.sub("Imgur\.Util\.triggerView'(?=\w{5,10})", "imgurl.com/", "Imgur.Util.triggerView'B1ahblA4")
```

> 'imgurl.com/B1ahblA4'

The pattern here is a simple string, so whatever you need to make dynamic you can use a variable for it. For example to use different mappings:

```
map = {
  'Imgur\.Util\.triggerView\'': 'imgurl.com/',
  'Example\.Util\.triggerView\'': 'example.com/'
}

items = [
  "Imgur.Util.triggerView'B1ahblA4",
  "Example.Util.triggerView'FooBar"
]

for item in items:
  for old, new in map.iteritems():
    pattern = old + '(?=\w{5,10})'
    if re.match(pattern, item):
      print re.sub(pattern, new, item)
```

> imgurl.com/B1ahblA4
>
> example.com/FooBar

Comment: I don't understand that. I just tried it out and it was not what I am looking for. I am trying to keep whatever I get for the \w{5,10} and change the beginning.

Comment: As you can see in the example that's happening. The part in the example input - as you did not provide other - that matches `\w{5,10}` is `qwertyu` and it is returned. Show your input :)

Comment: My input is varied. I guess I am trying to make that regex string a variable. Is that doable? If so, how?

Comment: Just saw your comment on the question. There you don't have a `(` in the input as opposed to the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can as well work this way:

```
import re
element = "Imgur.Util.triggerView('glglgl')"
galcode_scan = re.search(ur'Imgur\.Util\.triggerView\(\'(\w{5,10})\'\)', element)
```

Now you have a match object which you can furtherly use: with either of

```
galcode_scan.expand('replacement.\\1')
galcode_scan.expand('replacement.\g<1>')
```

you get `replacement.glglgl` as a result.

This works by applying the replacement string with the captured groups.